# What is a good use case for ViewChild read:ElementRef

Tags: angular

I know you can get access to DOM elements using ViewChild(..., {read: ElementRef}). But my question is why would you ever do this? Every use case I can think of is better accomplished with more typical Angular mechanisms.

Edit: To clarify, why would I ever want to access a DOM element directly from within my component when everything I can do with an element I can handle via bindings?

Answer (score 0):

With ViewChild referencing an Element you can consistantly get its changes because the decorator detects DOM changes, without it you would need to call a querySelector or something everytime inside a logic that detects change.

Lets say you have an `*ngFor` with an async variable as its list and you have to reference an element inside of the loop. You would need to wait for it to finish to be rendered in your screen and then use a query selector to get your element's data, ViewChild can help you do that since it will detect when your DOM has changed.

Comment: Thanks, but my real question is why would I even care to query for a DOM element in the first place. Most things I would want to do with an element I can already do with bindings.

Comment: Most of the times I use for focusing an input.
Also, there was a specific use case that I needed to create a dashboard that every card needed to be dynamic and I also needed to be able to sort these dashboard cards with drag and drop
Every card was a component, I created a wrapper component that basically had one div and inside this div an ng template that was used as reference to dinamically insert the components.
So i had a div that all of its children had to be ordered and dragged, this div had to be referenced with viewChild since i would need to interact with the childs from the parent

Comment: @JimCooper I am late to the party, but a good example is if you need a <canvas> rendering context.  In which case you need to `canvas.getContext("2d")` to achieve a RenderingContext which later code uses for dynamic drawing.